# How to access Twitter API using SoapUI?

Tags: soap, twitter

I have used the below code to run from  SoapUI, but I still get a missing property exception:

> No such property exists for class request

How do I resolve this issue?

```
def project = com.eviware.soapui.model.support.ModelSupport.getModelItemProject( request ) 

// initialize OAuth consumer     
def consumer = new oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer( project.getPropertyValue( "oauth_consumer_key" ), project.getPropertyValue( "oauth_consumer_secret" ));    
consumer.setTokenWithSecret( project.getPropertyValue( "oauth_access_token" ), project.getPropertyValue( "oauth_access_token_secret" )); 

// sign the request     
consumer.sign( context.httpMethod )
```

Comment: Is this Python? does the code work without the SoapUI testing framework?

Comment: this is groovy code piece which iam using in soap ui

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: took a look at the API guide, and it appears that you have the following:

```
def project = com.eviware.soapui.model.support.ModelSupport.getModelItemProject( request )
```

Then you call `project.getPropertyValue`. According to the [API guide](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/support/ModelSupport.html), there is no such method called `getPropertyValue` for `com.eviware.soapui.model.support.ModelSupport`.

There is a interface called [com.eviware.soapui.model.project](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/project/Project.html). Unless you're inheriting from [interface com.eviware.soapui.model.TestPropertyHolder](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/TestPropertyHolder.html#getPropertyValue%28java.lang.String%29), you're not going to get `getPropertyValue`.

---

To help resolve your issue, you'll need to debug into your code. Depending on the results from 'request' on your first line, you might very well *not* have the property `oauth_consumer_key`, `oauth_consumer_secret`, `oauth_access_token` or `oauth_access_token_secret`. Output the contents of `request` (or just set a break point in SoapUI at the `def project` and work through validating if you have the property).

Otherwise, there are a couple of alternate ways to tackle your problem. These are solutions geared towards using OAuth with SoapUI.

Try the **[following](http://www.soapui.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2964)**:

```
def gu = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );

def xml = gu.getXmlHolder( 'Authenticate - Default#Response' );
def token = xml.getNodeValue( '/auth/token' );
log.info( 'Got token: ' + token );

def suite = context.testCase.testSuite;
suite.setPropertyValue( 'auth_token', token );
log.info( 'Saved auth_token to suite.' );
```

The benefit of this code is that "the token sticks around in the TestSuite properties permanently. This has the side-effect/benefit of allowing me to run tests after the authentication test".

If that doesn't work, there's a **[great article here](http://xebee.xebia.in/2011/03/31/test-oauth-protected-rest-services-using-soapui/)** explaining how to do the OAuth against Vimeo; this should be very similar to the Twitter OAuth.

Neither of these solutions require SoapUI Pro.

Comment: It does not need SoapUI pro. This should work with the free SoapUI

Comment: According to **[this](http://xebee.xebia.in/2011/03/31/test-oauth-protected-rest-services-using-soapui/)** blog post (found in the answer), they are using the *free* '[Groovy Scripting Support](http://www.soapui.org/About-SoapUI/compare-soapui-and-soapui-pro.html)' found in the *free* version of SoapUI. This is precisely the answer you are looking for, including all the code necessary to get it to run.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have included here goes into the event tab in the PROJECT editor and you use a RequestFilter.filterRequest event to execute.  You also have to create custom properties for consumer_key, consumer_secret, oauth_acces_token, and oauth_acccess_token_secret.
Here is the guide on how to implement this on the smartbear website http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/twitter-sample-project.html